# Github Actions and Windows: using Cygwin bash instead of git-bash

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, github-actions

I am working with Github Actions running on Windows.  The image is `windows-2022` and has Cygwin installed a part of the workflow. As I have learned, the Windows image has git-bash on board already.

Cygwin is installed as follows:

```
- name: "Windows: Cygwin download"
  if: runner.os == 'Windows'
  run: |
    Invoke-WebRequest 'https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe' -OutFile 'setup-x86_64.exe'

- name: "Windows: Cygwin setup"
  if: runner.os == 'Windows'
  # The setup does not complete properly in powershell for some reason
  shell: cmd
  run: .\setup-x86_64.exe --quiet-mode --site http://cygwin.mirror.constant.com --symlink-type=sys --packages mingw64-i686-binutils=2.37-2,mingw64-x86_64-binutils=2.37-2,curl,diffutils,git,m4,make,mercurial,mingw64-i686-gcc-core,mingw64-i686-gcc-g++,mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core,mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++,patch,perl,rsync,unzip
```

When I specify `shell: bash` for a step, I find I cannot run any Cygwin tools. `bash --version` reports:

```
GNU bash, version 5.2.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
```

whereas `C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash --version` reports:

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)
```

So apparently I am running in `git-bash` rather than the Cygwin version.

How can I get GHA to execute a particular step (or all of them) in Cygwin’s version of bash, not git-bash?

Comment: Which Windows runner are you using? How did you check the cygwin there? Please include your relevant GHA workflow in your question. There's no cygwin installation mentioned in the preinstalled Windows runners. See the list of preinstalled software on [Windows Server 2019](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md) and [2022](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md).

Comment: Indeed, Cygwin is installed as part of the job (I did not build the script myself). I’ve edited the question to reflect that. The question then is: if I install Cygwin bash, how can I get the GHA image to use that instead of git-bash?

Comment: How did you install it e.g. via some other action?

Comment: Via two extra steps, see updated question

Comment: Right, a manual install it is. For any custom shell, you can specify it with `shell`. In your case, it should be the absolute path i.e. `shell: C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login '{0}'` or with other options as mentioned in this action (https://github.com/marketplace/actions/install-cygwin).

Comment: See [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].shell`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Configure Cygwin with `shell` like this:

```yaml
shell: C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login '{0}'
```

For all the steps, use [`defaults.run`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#defaultsrun). However, Cygwin is not preinstalled in Windows runners ([2019](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md) or [2022](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md)), at least for one step which installs Cygwin, you'll have to specify a different shell as you're already doing in your workflow.

For per-step shell configuration, you can use [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].shell`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell).

This action (https://github.com/marketplace/actions/install-cygwin) might be helpful for installing Cygwin instead of doing it yourself.

---

**UPDATE**

As mentioned by [koppor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873282/koppor) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75497452/github-actions-and-windows-using-cygwin-bash-instead-of-git-bash/75500329?noredirect=1#comment137755869_75500329), you may also use this official action to install Cygwin:

- https://github.com/marketplace/actions/install-cygwin-action

Comment: There is now an official Cygwin installation action: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/install-cygwin-action